# How to get CNTK Parallel Speedup on SequenceToSequence Example

Tags: cntk

I cloned the CNTK repository last week and built it using Nvidia-docker running on a p2.8xlarge instance on AWS. Everything appears to be working, except that I'm not getting a speedup from running multiple GPUs when enabling 1-bit SGD. I'm running the CMUDict Sequence2Sequence_distributed.py example. Here is my transcript when I run it on one GPU:

```
root@cb3aab88d4e9:/cntk/Examples/SequenceToSequence/CMUDict/Python# python Sequence2Sequence_Distributed.py
Selected GPU[0] Tesla K80 as the process wide default device.
ping [requestnodes (before change)]: 1 nodes pinging each other
ping [requestnodes (after change)]: 1 nodes pinging each other
requestnodes [MPIWrapperMpi]: using 1 out of 1 MPI nodes on a single host (1 requested); we (0) are in (participating)
ping [mpihelper]: 1 nodes pinging each other
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Build info:

                Built time: Jun  2 2017 19:46:11
                Last modified date: Fri Jun  2 19:21:14 2017
                Build type: release
                Build target: GPU
                With 1bit-SGD: yes
                With ASGD: yes
                Math lib: mkl
                CUDA_PATH: /usr/local/cuda
                CUB_PATH: /usr/local/cub-1.4.1
                CUDNN_PATH: /usr/local/cudnn
                Build Branch: master
                Build SHA1: 2bcdc9dff6dc6393813f6043d80e167fb31aed72
                Built by Source/CNTK/buildinfo.h$$0 on 72cb11c66133
                Build Path: /cntk
                MPI distribution: Open MPI
                MPI version: 1.10.3
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Finished Epoch[1 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.234002 * 64, metric = 98.44% * 64 3.014s ( 21.2 samples/s);
Finished Epoch[2 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.231473 * 71, metric = 85.92% * 71 1.013s ( 70.1 samples/s);
Finished Epoch[3 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.227827 * 61, metric = 81.97% * 61 0.953s ( 64.0 samples/s);
Finished Epoch[4 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.227088 * 68, metric = 86.76% * 68 0.970s ( 70.1 samples/s);
Finished Epoch[5 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.222957 * 62, metric = 88.71% * 62 0.922s ( 67.2 samples/s);
Finished Epoch[6 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.221479 * 63, metric = 84.13% * 63 0.950s ( 66.3 samples/s);
```

Here's the transcript when I run two GPUs:

> ```
> root@cb3aab88d4e9:/cntk/Examples/SequenceToSequence/CMUDict/Python# mpiexec --allow-run-as-root --npernode 2 python Sequence2Sequence_Distributed.py -q 1
>
>
> Selected GPU[0] Tesla K80 as the process wide default device.
> Selected CPU as the process wide default device.
> ping [requestnodes (before change)]: 2 nodes pinging each other
> ping [requestnodes (before change)]: 2 nodes pinging each other
> ping [requestnodes (after change)]: 2 nodes pinging each other
> ping [requestnodes (after change)]: 2 nodes pinging each other
> requestnodes [MPIWrapperMpi]: using 2 out of 2 MPI nodes on a single host (2 requested); we (0) are in (participating)
> ping [mpihelper]: 2 nodes pinging each other
> requestnodes [MPIWrapperMpi]: using 2 out of 2 MPI nodes on a single host (2 requested); we (1) are in (participating)
> ping [mpihelper]: 2 nodes pinging each other
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> Build info:
>
>                 Built time: Jun  2 2017 19:46:11
>                 Last modified date: Fri Jun  2 19:21:14 2017
>                 Build type: release
>                 Build target: GPU
>                 With 1bit-SGD: yes
>                 With ASGD: yes
>                 Math lib: mkl
>                 CUDA_PATH: /usr/local/cuda
>                 CUB_PATH: /usr/local/cub-1.4.1
>                 CUDNN_PATH: /usr/local/cudnn
>                 Build Branch: master
>                 Build SHA1: 2bcdc9dff6dc6393813f6043d80e167fb31aed72
>                 Built by Source/CNTK/buildinfo.h$$0 on 72cb11c66133
>                 Build Path: /cntk
>                 MPI distribution: Open MPI
>                 MPI version: 1.10.3
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> Build info: 
>
>                 Built time: Jun  2 2017 19:46:11
>                 Last modified date: Fri Jun  2 19:21:14 2017
>                 Build type: release
>                 Build target: GPU
>                 With 1bit-SGD: yes
>                 With ASGD: yes
>                 Math lib: mkl
>                 CUDA_PATH: /usr/local/cuda
>                 CUB_PATH: /usr/local/cub-1.4.1
>                 CUDNN_PATH: /usr/local/cudnn
>                 Build Branch: master
>                 Build SHA1: 2bcdc9dff6dc6393813f6043d80e167fb31aed72
>                 Built by Source/CNTK/buildinfo.h$$0 on 72cb11c66133
>                 Build Path: /cntk
>                 MPI distribution: Open MPI
>                 MPI version: 1.10.3
> -------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Here's an error message -- does this mean the GPUs are not being utilized when I run the job as two MPI processes? How would I fix this?

> ```
> NcclComm: disabled, at least one rank using CPU device
> NcclComm: disabled, at least one rank using CPU device
> ```

You can see the number of samples/s is down:

> ```
> Finished Epoch[1 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.233786 * 73, metric = 97.26% * 73 5.377s ( 13.6 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[1 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.233786 * 73, metric = 97.26% * 73 5.877s ( 12.4 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[2 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.232235 * 67, metric = 94.03% * 67 2.196s ( 30.5 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[2 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.232235 * 67, metric = 94.03% * 67 2.197s ( 30.5 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[3 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.229795 * 54, metric = 83.33% * 54 2.227s ( 24.2 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[3 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.229795 * 54, metric = 83.33% * 54 2.227s ( 24.2 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[4 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.229072 * 83, metric = 87.95% * 83 2.229s ( 37.2 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[4 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.229072 * 83, metric = 87.95% * 83 2.229s ( 37.2 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[5 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.227438 * 46, metric = 86.96% * 46 1.667s ( 27.6 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[5 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.227438 * 46, metric = 86.96% * 46 1.666s ( 27.6 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[6 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.225661 * 65, metric = 84.62% * 65 2.388s ( 27.2 samples/s);
> Finished Epoch[6 of 160]: [Training] loss = 4.225661 * 65, metric = 84.62% * 65 2.388s ( 27.2 samples/s);
> ```

Comment: One problem also seems to be that both processes seem to be reading the same training data, as they have identical loss numbers they are reporting. Is there documentation on how to fix this?

Comment: An update -- I found that my Nvidia-docker CNTK is not detecting more than one GPU. This may be the root of the problem. I'm investigating. When I run 'nvidia-smi' inside the docker container, I only see one GPU listed, but when I run it outside the docker container, I see eight GPUs listed. (This is a p2.8xlarge machine on AWS).

Comment: Ok. I was able to run the distributed ResNet and got great speedup using eight GPUs, with the training showing that the number of samples per second is way higher. Also -- it seemed that the training was converging much faster than it was on a single GPU. 

However, I'm not seeing the same speedup for the sequence2sequence_Distributed.py setup. It seems like each MPI worker is maybe processing the same training data, which seems like it's not the right thing. Also -- just my qualitative experience is that I didn't see a speedup. What is the state of this Seq2Seq distributed example?

Answer (score 0):

I was a able to fix the initial issue by getting Nvidia-docker to take multiple GPUs by telling the nvidia-docker which GPUs to use; for example -- if you want to set 2 GPUs, then use:

```
NV_GPU=0,1 nvidia-docker run ....
```

Comment: I'm still wondering how to get the speedup for the sequence to sequence model.

 I was able to run the distributed ResNet and got great speedup using eight GPUs, with the training showing that the number of samples per second is way higher. Also -- it seemed that the training was converging much faster than it was on a single GPU. However, I'm not seeing the same speedup for the sequence2sequence_Distributed.py setup. It seems like each MPI worker is maybe processing the same training data, which seems like it's not the right thing. 

What is the status of Sequence2Sequence_Distributed.py?

Answer (score 0):

By default Sequence2Sequence_distributed.py runs data parallel SGD with 32-bit. Can you try other distributed training algorithms, like block momentum with a warm-start?

Besides, consider increase your minibatch size (the default is 16) if you want better parallelism with multiple GPU. You can use nvidia-smi to check GPU utilization and memory usage.